# What is the (strong) dual of a projective/inductive limit?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

For a family of locally convex TVS $(E_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ it is a well known fact that the dual of the product is the sum of the individual duals and vice versa, i.e.
$$
\left(\prod_{\alpha \in A} E_\alpha\right)^{\prime} = \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} E_\alpha^\prime \quad\text{and}\quad \left(\bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} E_\alpha\right)^{\prime} = \prod_{\alpha \in A} E_\alpha^\prime.
$$

What I'd like to know is if there is a similar relationship between the duals of projective and inductive limits. So does, for example, hold that
$$
\left(\varprojlim E_\alpha\right)^\prime = \varinjlim E_\alpha^\prime \quad\text{and}\quad \left(\varinjlim E_\alpha\right)^\prime = \varprojlim E_\alpha^\prime?
$$

And does the strong topology on the dual coincide with the inductive/projective topology?

Where I'm trying to get to is: how does one find the "right" topology on $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)^\prime$ and describe the space "nicely" starting from the definition of $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as the inductive limit of $\mathcal{D}(K_m)$, where $\bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}}K_m = \mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact exhaustion. (Of course $\mathcal{D}(K_m)$ shall be the projective limit of the $k$-times differentiable functions with compact support in $K_m$.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Algebraically, there are canonical isomorphisms between the duals. However, for the strong topologies, things become very subtle. A Frechet space $E=\lim\limits_{\leftarrow} E_n$ with Banach spaces $E_n$ (and, of course, continuous linear connecting maps $\rho_{n+1}^n: E_{n+1}\to E_n$) is called *distinguished* if its strong dual is barrelled, and Grothendieck showed that then one has a *topological* isomorphism between $E'$ with its strong topology and $\lim\limits_{\to} E_n'$. There are however non-distinguished Frechet spaces (first examples of Köthe and Grothendieck, the strikingly simple example $C(\mathbb R) \cap L^1(\mathbb R)$ with its natural Frechet topology was found by Taskinen).

The "dual'' situation $(\lim\limits_\to E_n)'= \lim\limits_{\leftarrow} E_n'$ is slightly better: It holds topologically for all countable inductive limits of Banach spaces (Grothendieck), but for Frechet $E_n$ this may fail again.

In the particular case of $\mathscr D(\mathbb R^m)=\lim\limits_\to \mathscr D(K_n)$ you get topological equality of the dual $\mathscr D'(\mathbb R^m)$ and the projective limit of the duals because the inductive limit is *strict* and hence every bounded subset of the limit is contained and bounded in some "step" (which is very helpful to calculate the strong topologies).

Some books dealing with these things: Köthe's *Topological Vector Spaces*, Bonet's and Perez Carreras' *Barrelled Locally Convex Spaces* and Meise's and Vogt's *Introduction to Functional Analysis* and Wengenroth's (my) *Derived Functors in Functional Analysis*.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I've one question about it: are you including unbounded continuous functions in $C(\mathbb{R})$? since otherwise I'd be lead to think $C(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is also a Banach-space, or am I missing something else?

Comment: Yes, $C(\mathbb R)$ is the space of *all* continuous functions. The seminorms on the intersection are $\int |f(x|dx + \sup\limits_{|x|\le n} |f(x)|$.